# How do I find an available nickname? They all seem taken

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokémon Go is asking for a nickname, and I have entered dozens of names, but it has rejected every one saying that the name isn't available.

How can I find an available name?

Comment: Use more than one word, some misspellings & add numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public master list of taken nicknames to check against, which leaves only trying names until one works.

Pick unusual names. Try adding numbers onto the nicknames. Rearrange parts, change the spelling, or substitute letters with numbers in a nickname you like. Try unusual combinations of words.

Just keep thinking up nicknames until you think of one that isn't taken when you try it. All the common nicknames have been taken by now, so you'll have to get creative. For an example of the kinds of nicknames people have had to resort to, from where I'm sitting I can see a gym with pokémon owned by:

- V2NX
- Wandergirl29
- Saltyshrimp2016
- Chuiman91
- Horizons168
- secretcities
- Ssssssmart

These are higher-level players who picked their nicknames months ago, but you can see that even they had to resort to odd things, like unusual words, adding random numbers to the nickname, and other creative nonsense. Keep in mind that a name like **Ssssssmart** (6 esses) is different from **Sssssssmart** (7 esses).

Comment: Tag yourself, I'm SaltyShrimp. ;)